# Actionlisterner change the entire row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, invisible

I have JComboBox in my table. If user selected "Others" from the ComboBox i need to hide column number 3 in the table.

Code

```
        final TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
        col5.setPreferredWidth(150);
        final String EDIT = "edit";
        String[] options = new String[]{"Font Issue", "Text Issue", "Image Issue", "AI Issue", "Others"};
        JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox(options);
        JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox(options);
        col5.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo1));
        col5.setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer(combo2));
        combo2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String newSelection = col5.getCellEditor().getCellEditorValue().toString();
                String strOthersRemark = "";
                if (newSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("others")) {
                    jTable1.removeColumn(jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));
                }
            }
        });
```

The code working fine but with one small issue. When user select others it removed the entire column instead the row.For an example

```
Row|Column1 | Column2 | Column3  | Column4  |
 1 | Test11 | Test12  | Test13   | Test14   |
 2 | Test21 | Test22  | Test23   | Test24   |
 3 | Test31 | Test32  | Test33   | Others   |
```

When user select Column4 as `Others` it should hide the `Test33`, not entire `Column3`. My code remove entire `Column3`. What should I do if I want to hide `Test33` only

Comment: what you are doing is **wrong** (as already commented in one of your earlier questions) - it's crazy to act on state of a renderer (which is unpredictable at best)

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you elaborate more so i can fix my code.

Comment: it's as simple as: don't listen to _rendering_ components, don't access _editing_ components - both doesn't make sense. No offense meant, but if you dan't understand that, it's time to fresh up on Swing basics ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra can i change it to listen editing components and access the rendering components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing the column:

```
 jTable1.removeColumn(jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));
```

Instead you should change the value at certain cell.

Use this method instead: `table.setValueAt()`. Java doc: [setValueAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

In your example:

```
jTable1.setValueAt("", 3, 3);
```

Comment: added example, but please note that you'll have to read javadoc anyway to learn java